# TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I try to get data from LineEdit text giving to SQLite but i got below error and i get 1 problem that SQLite auto get "" text , eventhough GUI dont appear for me to type into EditLine

```
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

[('', '', 'Male', '<built-in method text of QLineEdit object at 0x7fc496171040>')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/baoduy/Desktop/GUI/run.py", line 35, in <module>
main_win = UI()
  File "/home/baoduy/Desktop/GUI/run.py", line 16, in __init__
self.Dktt = Dangkithongtin()
  File "/home/baoduy/Desktop/GUI/Dangkithongtin.py", line 29, in __init__
self.btnDangkithongtin.clicked.connect(self.INSERT_NOIDUNG(ID,Name,Gender,Birthday))

TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

```
from PyQt5 import uic
    from Dktt import Ui_dkttWindow
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem
    from classdb import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QTime, QDateTime, Qt
    
    mydb = MY_DB()
    
    class Dangkithongtin(QMainWindow):
        global mydb

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi("Dktt.ui",self)
    self.tableDulieu.setColumnWidth(0,70)
    self.tableDulieu.setColumnWidth(1,200)
    self.tableDulieu.setColumnWidth(2,120)
    self.tableDulieu.setColumnWidth(3,180)

    mydb.connect2()
    #mydb.create_table1()

    ID = self.txtbID.text()
    Name = self.txtbName.text()
    Gender = str(self.combGender.currentText())
    Birthday = self.txtbBirthday.text

    self.btnDangkithongtin.clicked.connect(self.INSERT_NOIDUNG(ID,Name,Gender,Birthday))
    #self.btnDangkithongtin.clicked.connect(self.INSERT_NOIDUNG("3","4","5","6"))
    #self.btnChinhsua.clicked.connect(self.Chinhsuadangki(Name,ID,Gender,Birthday))

def SHOWDB(self):
    self.result = mydb.select_all()
    print(self.result) 
    #show ảnh : truyền dữ liệu từ sql vào GUI bằng hàm setItem
    self.tableDulieu.setRowCount(0) #bắt đầu Row là dòng 0
    for row_num,row_data in enumerate(self.result):
        self.tableDulieu.insertRow(row_num) # thêm vào dòng mới
        for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):  
            self.tableDulieu.setItem(row_num,col_num,QTableWidgetItem(str(col_data)))
            # truyền vào stt cột và stt hàng , và dữ liệu QTableWidgetItem(str(col_data) dưới dạng str

def INSERT_NOIDUNG(self,ID,Name,Gender,Birthday):
    #mydb.insert_row_data("{ID}".format(ID=ID),"{Name}".format(Name=Name),"{Gender}".format,"{Birthday}",format(Birthday=Birthday))
    mydb.insert_row_data(f"{ID}",f"{Name}",f"{Gender}",f"{Birthday}")
    self.SHOWDB()
```

Comment: There's no `return` statement in `INSERT_NOIDUNG()`. But you're trying to use its return value as the argument to `connect()`

Comment: Even after correcting what pointed out above, `INSERT_NOIDUNG` will be called with the *default* values. Either use `self.txtbID.text()`, etc in the arguments of the lambda, or read those values in the function itself. `self.txtbBirthday.text` is also missing parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `connect()` should be a function to call, not a call to the function. Use `lambda` to call `self.INSERT_NOIDUNG()`

```
    self.btnDangkithongtin.clicked.connect(lambda: self.INSERT_NOIDUNG(ID,Name,Gender,Birthday))
```